# Phoenix, function in model schema

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

How to add function in schema? I want to create function for dynamically add fields to model schema. Example:

```
  def func do
    # .. loop to create dynamic fields
    field :street, :string
  end

  schema "objects" do
    func
  end

... Error:

** (CompileError) web/models/objects.ex:12: undefined function func/0
```

Answer (score 5):

`func` needs to be in a separate module since you want to call it from the body of this module. `func` also needs to be a macro that returns a quoted AST containing the `field` calls so that `field` is able to put the fields in the correct module since `field` too is a macro. You're looking for something like this:

```
defmodule MyApp.Post.Helper do
  defmacro func do
    quote do
      field :foo, :string
    end
  end
end

defmodule MyApp.Post do
  use MyApp.Web, :model
  import MyApp.Post.Helper

  schema "posts" do
    func()
  end
end
```

Test:

```
iex(1)> %Post{}
%MyApp.Post{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "posts">, foo: nil, id: nil}
```

Comment: Can I pass parameters to defmacro func..?

Comment: Yes, but it's not exactly like function parameters. You have to use quote/unquote. See http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/macros.html.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `defmacro` is not a function, it’s [a macro itself](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/edd38eee485789f88836866094f852a8f5e2ebfb/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L3462).